# Steps in Referencing UITabBarController from StoryBoard to AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, appdelegate

I'm using a code that programmatically creates a `UITabBarController` in appDelegate. What I already have is a TabBarController created in the StoryBoard. I want to reference my TabBarController(from storyboard) to appDelegate and replace the `UITabBarController` which was programmatically created. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code below:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [[UIStoryboard alloc] initWithStoryboard:[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"YourStoryboardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]];
UITabBarController *tabBarController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourTabBarControllerIDInStroyboard"];
```

Comment: One more question, should I put it in appDelegate.h?

Comment: it should be in appdelegate.m